# Acceptable range for standard error in MCMC simulation

Tags: standard-error, markov-chain-montecarlo

Is there a convention when it is acceptable to accept an estimate like an empiric mean generated by a MCMC run based on the value of the *standard error*, similar to Cohen's effect size categories?

Comment: What do you mean by "accept an estimate"? In terms of diagnosis whether your samples are actually coming from the posterior distribution of interest there are many convergence diagnostics you can look at, I'd also look at trace plots, effective sample size, autocorrelations, and cross-correlations

Comment: @bdeonovic When do we halt the MCMC run, because we think the estimate we got is close enough to the true value and accept the estimate?

Comment: You don't get an estimate from MCMC, you get a distribution for a variable. Thats why diagnosing convergence can be tricky.

Comment: What I'm trying to get at is that there is not a good answer to your question: it depends on your model, your priors, your sampling method, your data, etc.

Comment: There exist spectral estimates of the asymptotic variance of your MCMC-based estimate, as well as alternatives based on the effective sample size (ESS) that relate the number of performed MCMC iterations to a virtual number of iid simulations from the same target.